# Is the Amazon rainforest the "world's lungs"?

Tags: amazon-rainforest

The 72 million Google results for "[Amazon world lungs](https://www.google.com/search?q=amazon+world%27s+lung)" (unquoted) is evidence enough that there's a common perception that the Amazon rainforest is the "world's lungs". God knows I grew up believing that.

At one point I read that this was incorrect, since the forest consumes just as much oxygen as it produces. But then I was told that was just anti-environmental propaganda.

Now with the Amazon fires all over the news, I've started hearing this once again (for example, this [Forbes article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/michaelshellenberger/2019/08/26/why-everything-they-say-about-the-amazon-including-that-its-the-lungs-of-the-world-is-wrong/#3971eb205bde)). So, is the Amazon a (significant) net source of oxygen?

If not, how adequate are the substitutes mentioned in that article (i.e. soy farms and cow pastures)?

(And, if this doesn't extend the scope of the question too much: if (rain)forests aren't net sources of oxygen, what is?)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98017/discussion-on-question-by-wasabi-is-the-amazon-rainforest-the-worlds-lungs).

Comment: Another answer outside of this site: https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2019/08/amazon-fire-earth-has-plenty-oxygen/596923/

Comment: related https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/which-consumes-more-carbon-dioxide-a-fully-grown-forest-or-a-newly-planted-one

Answer (score 134):

I'm not sure where have I first stumbled upon this information, but I think it was during my childhood when media was not centered on the rain forests so much. The primary oxygen production on Earth is actually happening in oceans. Here are few articles I found:

- [Oceans produce ~80% of world's oxygen](https://eos.org/research-spotlights/worlds-biggest-oxygen-producers-living-in-swirling-ocean-waters)
- [Phytoplankton produces 50-85% of atmosphere's oxygen](https://earthsky.org/earth/how-much-do-oceans-add-to-worlds-oxygen)

This article says that [scientists prefer term oxygen turnover](https://www.reference.com/science/much-oxygen-rainforest-produce-6183d08637f543b7). The term production is very misleading. Rain forests actually produce about as much as they consume because of decomposing plants and animals.

Although media nowadays may say the Amazon is the lungs of our planet, I wouldn't justify burning it just because the forest is not an oxygen producer. It is still a part of nature and burning it can narrow the diversity of both plants and animals, which can have consequences on the whole planet.

Comment: It's worth noting that mature trees are a natural carbon sink, as their growth removed a lot of carbon dioxide from the atmosphere, storing it in the form of cellulose and other ligneous matter. So while the recent fires have little effect on the forest's ability to remove atmospheric carbon, they just released a whole bunch of it. And since new (young) trees are likely not going to be planted because of Brazil's economic situation, this atmospheric carbon is not going to go away any time soon.

Comment: @Dungarth That would make for a great additional answer (with some sources)

Comment: @Dungarth recent, more comprehensive research indicates this may not be true. The idea of trees "maturing" is based on a single old study that hasn't stood up to scrutiny. Take a look at the answer I wrote on [Sustainability.SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/6967/3379) discussing the research.

Comment: @LShaver That was an interesting read, thank you. However, this study only measures "by tree" rather than "by hectare", which could lead to significantly different conclusions. Indeed, a forest's productivity (it's capacity to store carbon) strongly correlates with tree density (the # of trees in a given area). So while it's true that a mature tree is more efficient at stocking carbon than a young tree, you can have multiple young trees in the area required for that mature tree to grow. So while I'm not saying you are wrong, a truly comprehensive study would take that into account.

Comment: @Dungarth What you elaborate is correct, but your terminology is not. A (current) carbon *sink* is something that is *at present* actively removing carbon from the atmosphere -- the same way a sink is draining water --, which a grown tree does **not.** Old trees *were* sinks when they were growing; i.e. *young*, growing  trees are carbon sinks. Old trees are carbon *storage* (as you elaborate correctly).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Thank you for the precision! English isn't my native language and I'm less familiar with the proper terms.

Comment: Since this is StackExchange and pedantry is important....

I'm not sure a sink has to be currently, um, sink-ing, does it? A sink that has sunk is still a sink.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider : This is nonsensical.  Trees that are not dead continue to produce growth rings and capture carbon to expand, even if they do not continue to increase their height.  *Old* trees do not stop capturing atmospheric carbon and sinking it.  In fact, once a tree is approximately its asymptotic height, each year's growth (on average) captures more carbon than the previous year's because the volumes of growth rings scale with the surface area of the tree.

Comment: @EricTowers We agree that only a plant/system accumulating biomass constitutes a carbon sink; I simply suppose that "grown trees" do not accumulate much mass any more. Now "grown tree" is a vague term; but surely an old tree eventually starts to degrade and lose biomass (rots from the inside, loses branches, loses leaves overall). So there will be a prior point when a "grown tree" is carbon balanced. A *growing tree*, by contrast, necessarily captures carbon overall.

Comment: Everyone always ignores the huge amount of rainforest on other continents.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider : Real data, e.g., https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0181187 , https://www.nature.com/articles/nature12914 , https://www.nature.com/articles/nature12914 does not show a plateau or downturn with advanced age.

Comment: @EricTowers Looks as if the "missing consensus" on the issue which both papers lament is tilting towards "continuous carbon sink". Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider : Thanks for the subtle hint.  There was a cut-and-paste bobble with the third link: https://www.npr.org/2014/01/16/262479807/old-trees-grow-faster-with-every-year (which is a popular article describing the second link, but much more succinctly).

Comment: @duality_ : another factor for the large amount of downvotes might be that this topic is so heavily politicized, and many people's freind-or-foe identifier triggers automatically. If one faction bases its political campaign on how they want to save the planet and that everyone else is evil and wants to destroy it, then if they say that the Amazon rainforest produces almost all of the planet's oxygen, then any argument refuting this statement is classified as coming from "the enemy".

Answer (score 52):

The Forbes article asserting the Amazon contributes net zero is correct.  The link below shows the environmental science to back it up and also adds an important conclusion about our sources of oxygen.

http://www.yadvindermalhi.org/blog/does-the-amazon-provide-20-of-our-oxygen

> The oxygen levels in the atmosphere are set on million year timescales by the subtle balance of geological, chemical and biological processes. They are not set by the short term (short term equals anything less than hundreds of thousands of years) activities or existence of current biomes.
>
> A final point to make is that the atmosphere is awash with oxygen, at 20.95% or 209,500 ppm (parts per million). Carbon dioxide, by comparison, is around 405 ppm, over 500 times less than oxygen, and rising by around 2-3 ppm per year. Human activity (around 90% of which being fossil fuel combustion) has caused this oxygen concentration to drop by around 0.005% since 1990, a trivial amount. In parallel, the same activities have caused carbon dioxide concentrations to rise by by 37 ppm since 1990, or 10%. This is a much more substantial percentage because there is so little carbon dioxide in the atmosphere to begin with, so human activities that emit or absorb carbon dioxide can make a major difference. This is why we need to worry about the increase of  carbon dioxide in the atmosphere (and its resulting impact on climate), and why we don't need to worry about running out of oxygen

Edit: A new article in The Atlantic explains this in much simpler language.

https://amp.theatlantic.com/amp/article/596923/

> This is what we are burning at Earth’s surface today. We’re not just burning down the Amazon. We’re burning down all the forests in Earth history that we can get our hands on. For every worrying part per million that CO2 goes up from burning fossil fuels, atmospheric oxygen goes down an equivalent amount, and then some. As a result, oxygen is dropping far faster from burning fossil fuels, and their untold forests, than it is from burning just the trees available on the planet’s surface. We’re reversing tens of millions of years of photosynthesis all at once.

Comment: Be aware that, when talking about the "lungs of the world", the "production of oxygen" is equivalent to "reduction of CO2". Also note that suffocation in a closed system usually happens by means of CO2 poisoning, not lack of oxygen. Actually, your blog then goes on to show that, indeed, the rainforests are where the majority of land-based photosynthesis happens. So it basically wants to keep its cake *and* eat it...

Comment: (ctd.) As for the point being missed, yes, the oxygen - carbon dioxide - oxygen cycle is, effectively, a zero-sum affair. There is no big "carbon sink" on this planet (because if there were, plants would die, as they *need* CO2). That's why *adding* carbon to the atmosphere and *removing* what photosynthesis capacities there are is such a disastrous thing. So saying "we don't need to worry" can't be "a correct answer" by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: @DevSolar : the quote includes *"we need to worry about the increase of carbon dioxide in the atmosphere"*, which seems to be in agreement with your comment.

Comment: Not the fault of the answer, but it seems to be unnecessarily hard to compare "0.005%" for O2 and "37 ppm" for CO2 in the quote's figures. If I'm counting correctly, 0.005% is the same as 50 ppm.

Comment: @DevSolar How does it change the quote's point, which is that the carbon dioxide increase is going to kill us long before we start feeling the decrease in oxygen concentration? In any case, you're missing the point anyway, since "net zero oxygen production" already includes the rainforest biomass decomposing into carbon dioxide! It's already a balanced cycle, not with the rest of the world, but merely with itself. Now, replacing that with cow pastures would still be bad, for many reasons, but replacing it with a marsh or common farmland (especially something organic) wouldn't (for oxygen ofc).

Comment: @Luaan: I think you are mistaken on several levels, but nevermind, this is about my criticism on the source quote. It gives the impression -- to me, whom I am not a native speaker -- of giving the subject matter a spin of "don't worry, be happy" by doing a "don't look here, look over there" shtick.

Comment: @DevSolar "the rainforests are where the majority of **land-based** photosynthesis happens". This does not make them "the world's lungs" since the oceans release more oxygen than forests, maybe up to 80% of the total.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The article compares 0.005% change in O2 to 10% change in CO2. Sure, it also states the CO2 change in ppm, but it does give values in percent for a direct comparison.

Comment: Writers are taught to avoiding repeating the same words a lot in order to keep things interesting, which is great in general, but they rarely seem to realize that this should not apply to things (like units) that ought to be compared very directly.

Answer (score 27):

tl;dr - **yes**, but there are doubts that it will keep being "world's lungs" in the future.

The removal of athmospehric CO<sub>2</sub> and the production of oxygen are two sides of the same process, while the former is much easier to estimate and measure. And terrestrial ecosystems play an important role in the CO<sub>2</sub> absorption, taking up roughly as much CO<sub>2</sub> as ocean biomes, despite their smaller area:

[image]

<sup>(figure from [*Balancing the Global Carbon Budget*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9804/a0a472efb0bf63997827f38ef126c8a97475.pdf), R.A. Houghton, 2007)</sup>

However, it's important to note that rainforests sequester the carbon primarily in the biomass, as opposed to biomes deemed effective carbon storages, such as swamps or mangroves:

[image]

Practically this means that while tropical forests are very effective short-time CO<sub>2</sub> absorbers, they relatively quickly reach an equilibrium after which they [lose nearly as much CO<sub>2</sub> from decay as they gain from photosynthesis](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature14283).

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have data on *total* tCO2eq, i.e. taking into account the area actually *covered* by the respective biomes?

Comment: How does a summary of "yes" derive from the fact given in your last paragraph? The Amazon is a forest, not just a group of trees. CO2 and O2 use is balanced.

Comment: @DevSolar No, I haven't seen such data yet. One could pick area figures from Wikipedia and multiply. Mangroves are quite widespread but typically cover a very narrow piece of land (seashore) compared to rainforests.

Comment: What makes mangrove and swamps different from trees in terms of carbon sequestration?  Is their growing faster than decomposing? Or is that immediately buried in oceans? It is a point of the balance I don't understand. I have trouble with photosynthesis as source of oxygen if the died organism aren't buried deep as it happened in geological past. Can you point me to the right way of looking at this?

Comment: @Alchimista Mangroves store a lot of carbon in the soil, like swamps do. Growth and decomposing will always balance out in the end, but a mangrove will store 2000 ton/ha of CO2 at that point, compared to 700 ton/ha for a tropical forest.

Comment: Thank you. And what about the diatomes (not sure about spelling, I mean the micro algae with silicates skeletons).

Comment: @Alchimista Those probably sequester CO2 forever (on a human scale) if they happen to fall on the seabed. This happens very slowly though: as the first picture shows, land ecosystems absorb CO2 much quicker.